Characterizing regular tree languages of polynomial growth
Let $L$ be a regular tree language and $C(n)$ be the number of trees in $L$ of size $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Is there a "structural" condition on $L$ that is equivalent to $C(n) = n^{O(1)}$?
There are reasons to believe that there should be. If $L'$ is a context-free word language and $C'(n)$ counts its words of size $n$, then $C'(n) = n^{O(1)}$ if and only if $L'$ is a "bounded language", which means that there exist words $w_1,\dots,w_k$ such that $L' \subseteq (w_1)^* \dots (w_k)^*$. (According to the introduction of https://doi.org/10.1142/S0129054110007441 "this result has been independently discovered at least six times".) Moreover, regular tree languages can be encoded as context-free word languages in a size-preserving way (e.g. using reverse Polish notation). So $C(n) = n^{O(1)}$ if and only if the language of encodings of trees in $L$ is bounded.
But I wonder whether some necessary and sufficient condition can be stated directly on the shape of the trees themselves. Does something like this exist in the literature?

Let $\Sigma$ be a ranked alphabet, and let $T(\Sigma)$ be the set of all finite $\Sigma$-labeled trees. A regular tree language $L \subseteq T(\Sigma)$ is recognized by a finite tree automaton $A = (Q, \Sigma, \delta, F)$. We measure the size of a tree $t$ by its number of nodes, denoted $|t|$, and let $C(n)$ be the number of trees in $L$ of size $n$. We wish to characterize when $C(n) = n^{O(1)}$ using only tree-structural properties.
To capture boundedness, augment $\Sigma$ by adding placeholder symbols $\{\diamond_1, \dots, \diamond_m\}$ of specified arities, forming $\Sigma_\diamond = \Sigma \cup \{\diamond_1,\dots,\diamond_m\}$. Choose a finite set $\mathcal{T} = \{T_1,\dots,T_k\} \subseteq T(\Sigma_\diamond)$ of template trees. Each template $T_i$ is a finite $\Sigma_\diamond$-tree that may contain placeholders. Define a composition function
$$\phi : (\mathcal{T} \cup T(\Sigma))^p \longrightarrow T(\Sigma),$$
which replaces each placeholder $\diamond_j$ in a template by an input tree of matching arity, preserving the overall tree structure. For any sequence of input trees $(S_1,\dots,S_p)$, the result $\phi(S_1,\dots,S_p)$ is an ordinary $\Sigma$-tree. This operation is well-defined in the sense that each $\diamond_j$ has a fixed number of children, and only subtrees of the correct rank can be substituted.
A tree $t \in T(\Sigma)$ admits a $(\mathcal{T},\phi)$-decomposition of depth $p$ if there is a sequence $(S_1,\dots,S_p)$ with each $S_\ell \in \mathcal{T}\cup T(\Sigma)$ such that
$$t = \phi(S_1,\dots,S_p).$$
The depth $p$ corresponds to how many times we apply the composition function $\phi$. Say that $L$ is template bounded with depth $O(\log n)$ if every tree $t\in L$ of size $n$ admits such a decomposition of depth at most $c \log(n)$ for some constant $c$. This template-boundedness is the direct tree analog of "boundedness" in word languages and results in the following equivalence:

If $L$ is template bounded, then $C(n) \leq n^{O(1)}$. Since there are only finitely many templates in $\mathcal{T}$ and each decomposition for a size-$n$ tree has depth at most $c\log(n)$, the number of ways to pick templates at each step is at most $k^{O(\log n)}$, which is $n^{O(1)}$. Once the sequence $(S_1,\dots,S_p)$ is fixed, the result of $\phi$ is unique, preventing exponential blow-up.

Conversely, if $C(n) \leq n^{O(1)}$, we can encode $L$ size-preservingly into a context-free word language $L' \subseteq \Sigma'^*$. Polynomial growth of $L$ implies polynomial growth of $L'$, which implies $L'$ is a bounded context-free language in the classic sense $\subseteq w_1^* \cdots w_\ell^*$. Translating that bounded structure back to the tree world produces a finite set of tree templates together with a composition operation that reconstructs each tree of $L$ in at most logarithmic depth. The placeholders $\diamond_j$ in each template correspond to subtrees recognized by certain states of the underlying finite tree automaton, ensuring that no step in the decomposition can branch in an unbounded manner.


